# No variable declared as function, but Error: invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program to delete leading spaces in a poorly formatted C++ program. I get this error in line 24: `cout << removeLeadingSpaces(s) << endl;`, please help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string removeLeadingSpaces(string line)
{
bool start = false;
string newline;
for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
{
    if (!isspace(line[i]) && start==false)
    {
    start = true;       
    }
    if (start==true)
        newline += line[i];
 }
return newline;
 }

 void printindented()
{
string s;
while (getline(cin, s))
    cout << removeLeadingSpaces(s) << endl;
}

int main() 
{
    cout << printindented() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: you're trying to print void value in " cout << printindented() << endl;"

Comment: Please include the full error traceback in your question.

Comment: I'm sure it's deliberately ironic that your own indentation is all over the gaff.

Answer (score 2):

The problematic line is

```
cout << printindented() << endl;
```

in `main`. The line

```
cout << removeLeadingSpaces(s) << endl;
```

in `printindented` is just fine.

Change the line in `main` to:

```
printindented();
```

Answer (score 1):

In int main you're trying to print a function that returns `void` which is causing the error. Also you should use proper indentation and next time word your question a bit better by giving more insight into the problem.
Fixed code

```
int main() 
{
    printindented(); // Can't print void cout << printindented() << endl;
}
```